# How to create a timetable generator from multiple time slot choices for different courses?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am thinking of a project to create a timetable generator to solve one issue faced in university. Before every new semester, there will be a preview of timetable of different courses for us to choose. Each course has multiple slots, for example Lecture 1, Lecture 2, Tutorial 1, Tutorial 2, etc. In this scenario, we have to choose one lecture and one tutorial class for each course. With many courses that have to be chosen (usually 5 courses), we need to arrange the time slots for each class without crashing.

The requirements are as below:

- 1 class for lecture and tutorial class each course
- No time crashing
- Able to compute all possible combinations without time crashing.

I am familiar with Python and wish to go with this language. Is there any direction, algorithm or possible solution that I can refer to solve this matter? I would like to create it as a side project.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, the _timetable_ is already generated -- what you're actually trying to do is find all possible combinations of 5 (lecture, tutorial) tuples that a student can take, given the (already generated) timetable. Is that correct?

Comment: @butterflyknife yup you are right, I am thinking to find all possible combination of suitable courses with their timeslots